# Error in my code

Tags: javascript, php

Why my this fill is not working and how to correct error ....I am new here

```
sign_creator($data); // Creates a GET array for arrays $data
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
var page = "';
echo 'https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?'.http_build_query($data); // Show out link results
echo '";
var $dialog = $('<div></div>') .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>') 
.dialog(
{ autoOpen: false, modal: true, height: 625, width: 500, title: "Some title" }
);
 $dialog.dialog('open');
</script>';




?>
```

Comment: Help me sanket makani

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please update your question to clearly state what you expect to happen and then show the actual output. You should aim to do this in your questions if you want people to take the time to help you out. Also avoid pleading for help, it doesn't add value to the site and is actively discouraged here. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape single quotes, try this:

```
<?php 
sign_creator($data); // Creates a GET array for arrays $data
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
var page = "';
echo 'https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?'.http_build_query($data); // Show out link results
echo '";
var $dialog = $(\'<div></div>\') .html(\'<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="\' + page + \'" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>\') 
.dialog(
{ autoOpen: false, modal: true, height: 625, width: 500, title: "Some title" }
);
 $dialog.dialog(\'open\');
</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

When use single quote for define string in php and you want to use it in string, you must use backslash(`\`) to tell php it's only character and not code.

```
sign_creator($data); // Creates a GET array for arrays $data
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
var page = "';
echo 'https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?'.http_build_query($data); // Show out link results
echo '";
var $dialog = $("<div></div>").html(\'<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>\') 
.dialog(
{ autoOpen: false, modal: true, height: 625, width: 500, title: "Some title" }
);
 $dialog.dialog(\'open\');
</script>';

?>
```

But you can use following code to echo string out of php tags:

```
sign_creator($data); // Creates a GET array for arrays $data
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var page = "https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?<?php echo http_build_query($data) ?>";
    var $dialog = $("<div></div>").html('<iframe style="border: 0px;" src="' + page+ '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>').dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, height: 625, width: 500, title: "Some title" });
    $dialog.dialog('open');
</script>
```